# What font is the "Sears Roebuck & Co" found on the doors to some Sears stores?

Tags: font-identification

Here it is:

[image: Picture of Sears Sign]

I've seen some Sears stores in Maryland that have gold lettering on the glass front door saying *SEARS ROEBUCK & CO.*. It's something older-fashioned looking and very widely spaced, maybe Caslon? Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Got a photo of one of the doors?

Comment: Are you asking us to drive to Sears? ;) Otherwise, my guess is that if it *is* old fashioned looking, it's likely an old sign painted by a lettering artist. In which case it wouldn't be a font but hand lettering. Alternatively, it may be a faux-vintage sign using one of Sears original logos--which is also likely hand lettered.

Comment: Def you need to provide a source image please.

Comment: -1 due to no follow-up from asker.  It's tough to offer help when the question is vague and abandoned.

Comment: @Farray, mea maxima culpa. I don't think there's any way this question can be answerable without a photo, and I haven't been to Sears recently. Perhaps "vague and abandoned", but not intentionally so!

Comment: A question isn't inherently bad because a handful of people in a particular venue cannot answer it.

Comment: @user A question is not high-quality when it omits necessary contextual information.  Without such information, any answer is really just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From 1970 - 1984 Sears used, I believe, Bodoni or Century for their logo. The family looks like Century to me, though the 'R' looks a bit more like Century Old Style. It could be one of the hybrid off-shoots of century, or the 'R' might have been purposely tweaked to give some uniqueness.

Depending on age, do keep in mind, that pre computer era, there were a lot of proprietary systems and the sign company may have simply substituted the closest font they had in their system.

If I had to dup this for a job, I’d start with the closest Century, Century Schoolbook, Century Book, I had on hand and if I had the same weight replace the ‘R’ with my closest Century Old.

**[Baskerville Com Medium](http://www.fonts.com/findfonts/detail.htm?productid=191233)** is also close.

Comment: I don't know how old the store is; any way to tell whether it's a real old sign, or was recently made in a retro style?

Comment: It is a bit hard to say. It might be helpful if you gave some idea of what level of accuracy you actually need. Is this a something you're just curious about, is it for a client, are you replacing the sign etc. If you want close or very close I think you're there. If you want exact, more information would be helpful.

Comment: As to the age of the building, the building itself might give some clue (photo doesn’t show enough). Though it might be easier to go into the store and ask around. If the person you ask doesn’t know, ask them to direct you to the person who should. It is highly likely that someone in management should have some idea how old the building is.